# Python Problem with locating elements [selenium][chorme webdriver]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate the buttons on the website. The HTML code shows as,

```
<div class="mv-button-group mv-stack-block mv-hyperlink-group">
    <div class="mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button mv-item-selected">Week</div>
    <div class="mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button">Month</div>
    <div class="mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button">Quarter</div>
    <div class="mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button">Season</div>
    <div class="mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button">Year</div>
</div>
```

There are in total five buttons, week, month, quarter, season, and year. Now the week button is selected, so the class name shows with the addition text 'mv-item-selected'. Since the buttons don't have an id or name, if I use the class name it will only return the first one. So how can I locate these buttons? thanks

Comment: `find_elements_by_class_name()` will return all the elements, not just the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways :

1. Use directly text on the buttons like :

   ```
   //div[text()='Month']
   ```

or

```
//div[text()='Quarter']
```

2. Use `xpath` indexing :-

   ```
   (//div[contains(@class, 'mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button')])[1]
   ```

or

```
(//div[contains(@class, 'mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button')])[2]
```

and so on..

in these two technique, we are basically using **xpaths**.

in code you can try it like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Month']").click()
```

or using **explicit waits** :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[contains(@class, 'mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button')])[2]"))).click()
```

You'll need the below **imports** :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

3. 3rd way would be to use `find_elements`

**Sample code :**

```
all_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'mv-button-base mv-hyperlink-button')]")
all_buttons[0].click() # to click on first item


all_buttons[1].click() # to click on second item

and so on..
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get all the buttons, right?

You are using the function `find_element_by_class_name()` therefore you'll only get the first child that matches the class name. In order to get all the elements with that class you have to use the "plural" version of the same funcion:
`find_elements_by_class_name()` (elements instead of element). This will return a list with all the child elements that match the class name.

Does this answer your question?